# how to pass a type parameter and compare with object type

Tags: ios, swift

I an learning the generic portion of Swift, and want to implement something like get a object according to the parameter.

The code seems like:

```
public func getChartRenderer(classType: anyClass) -> ChartDataRendererBase?
{
    for renderer in _renderers
    {
        if renderer.dynamicType is anyClass
        {
            return renderer
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

This is how I call it:

```
let rendererType = LineChartRenderer.self
if let lineChartRenderer = renderer.getChartRenderer(rendererType) {
    // do something
}
```

But I never get it work... I certainly misunderstood something, but I tried google, but still not clear how to do it. Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `isKindOfClass`

```
public func getChartRenderer(classType: AnyClass) -> ChartDataRendererBase?
{
    for renderer in _renderers
    {
        if renderer.isKindOfClass(classType)
        {
            return renderer
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: _renderers just contains all the renderer objects, their class is sub class of ChartDataRendererBase. I am not sure how to write it correctly so I just use anyClass at first. Could you update your answer based on my code?

Comment: _renderers are defined as `internal var _renderers = [ChartDataRendererBase]()`

Comment: check edit answer and also don't forget to inherit class ChartDataRendererBase from NSObject

Comment: I found `if renderer.dynamicType === classType` is also working? defined like this: `public func getChartRenderer(objectType: ChartDataRendererBase.Type)`

Comment: I don't know what is `dynamicType` property... I don't see what it is, because it isn't defined in NSObject or any other class. Maybe it is your internal property... Not sure that it works

Comment: No, it seems like built-in stuff in swift.

Comment: Yep, you right, `dynamicType` this isn't class property - it is reserved keyword of Swift.